# Do I need a server to run a .net framework web application?

Tags: asp.net

Is a server needed for the .net framework to run a .net web application on my local machine?

The application is on my local machine and I have configured it in IIS. I am connecting a server(xxx). Does xxx need the .net framework to run a .net web application at my local machine?

Comment: This question does not make sense as written. Do you mean "Does an IIS server need the .NET framework to run an application on my local machine?"...

Comment: I love the new `don net framework`. It is so cool:)

Comment: English may not be his first language - anyway i reckon yes is the answer :)

Comment: The `donnet` framework is the evolution of the `bonnet` framework:  The haberdashery web solution.

Comment: @controlfreak see the Tigger's answer..

Comment: @Tigger see the Controlfreak answer\

Comment: @Tigger I am far from considering everyone knows English, but this post is simply lacking any effort. I consider at least he knows how the framework he uses is written.

Comment: i'm a child.. give a solution..

Comment: I tried to clean it up as best I could, but native speaker or not, you **must** do a better job expressing your question if you expect to get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Or no (see comments).

Comment: what you think about Mr.controlfreak

Comment: Yes.  The Answer is yes.  In order to run a .net application one would need the .net framework.

Comment: Hi Stephen don't get angry.. why i'm asking so many times.. i have to ask to my sys admin to install.  so, my app is at my local pc and server is at another place.. now that server need framework to run app? which is at local or no need... at my local pc i have framework 2.0.. so is my server need or not?

Comment: Okay, if the server is going to run the application from YOUR local machine, then no.  The server does not need .Net (why would I get angry? :) )

Answer (score 1):

The server does not need the .NET Framework to access your local application if it is an ASP.NET web application/web site. If you want to move the application from your local box to the server machine so the server hosts the application, the server will need the .NET Framework and IIS.